# AWS Lambda Function: Cannot read property 'logs' 'numberOfPages' 'stream' of undefined. Package issue or AWS Lambda issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, html-to-pdf

Im doing conversion of html to pdf function on **AWS Lambda** using **phantom-html-to-pdf** package with Nodejs. I had encountered some errors which shows

> Cannot read property 'logs' of undefined

I try to comment it and it shows another error which is

> Cannot read property 'numberOfPages' of undefined

I'm not sure is it the error of the package or because it won't work on **AWS Lambda** . Also not sure why all the function inside async is not working.

Here's the code :

```
const fs = require("fs");
var phantomjs = require("phantomjs");
const conversion = require("phantom-html-to-pdf")({});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log("Start");
  conversion(
    { html: "<h1>Hello World</h1>" },
    // eslint-disable-next-line handle-callback-err
    async (err, pdf) => {
      const output = fs.createWriteStream("output.pdf");
      console.log("Process");
      console.log(pdf.logs);
      console.log(pdf.numberOfPages);
      // since pdf.stream is a node.js stream you can use it
      // to save the pdf to a file (like in this example) or to
      // respond an http request.
      pdf.stream.pipe(output);
      console.log("Done");
      callback(null, "done");
    }
  );
  console.log("End");
};
```

Here's the error :

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
  "errorMessage": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'logs' of undefined",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'logs' of undefined",
    "    at process.on (/var/runtime/index.js:37:15)",
    "    at process.emit (events.js:198:13)",
    "    at emitPromiseRejectionWarnings (internal/process/promises.js:140:18)",
    "    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:69:34)"
  ]
}
```

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
  "errorMessage": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'numberOfPages' of undefined",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'numberOfPages' of undefined",
    "    at process.on (/var/runtime/index.js:37:15)",
    "    at process.emit (events.js:198:13)",
    "    at emitPromiseRejectionWarnings (internal/process/promises.js:140:18)",
    "    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:69:34)"
  ]
}
```

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
  "errorMessage": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'stream' of undefined",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'stream' of undefined",
    "    at process.on (/var/runtime/index.js:37:15)",
    "    at process.emit (events.js:198:13)",
    "    at emitPromiseRejectionWarnings (internal/process/promises.js:140:18)",
    "    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:69:34)"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a lambda issue. It looks like `pdf` is null - I think you're supposed to check the `err` before using `pdf`. Also, I think that the function is not supposed to be `async`.

Comment: Ya, I did notice that the pdf seems to be null. I will try and update here later.

Answer (score 0):

Update!!!

I tried to change whatever name I want, it works fine. If I delete the `pdf`, it just wont work. Same issues as previous error. What is actually going on here?

```
const fs = require("fs");
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var phantomjs = require("phantomjs");
const conversion = require("phantom-html-to-pdf")({});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
console.log("Start");
conversion(
  { html: "<h1>Hello World</h1>" },
  // eslint-disable-next-line handle-callback-err
  function(err, haha) {
    const output = fs.createWriteStream("output.pdf");
    console.log("Process");
    //console.log(test.logs);
    //console.log(test.numberOfPages);
    // since pdf.stream is a node.js stream you can use it
    // to save the pdf to a file (like in this example) or to
    // respond an http request.
    haha.stream.pipe(output);
    console.log("Done");
    callback(null, "done");
  }
);
console.log("End");
};
```